# How can I send private message to Facebook?

Tags: 7, rules, social-network

I tried to build next feature using Drupal 7. When my site has new content, users get message about it into e-mail and Facebook private message. As for e-mail I not see any problem, but about FB private message I have not any idea. 
I know about username@facebook.com way. But how it works for users, who not have username (only ID)? Any other idea?

How can I do it? Can you give me right direction?

Thx for any answer. 
Best.

Comment: What do you mean by no username, only ID? Every person on Facebook should have a username.

You can always add a separate field when a person signs up for content notifications (or creates an account, etc.) - let them give you their Facebook username, then use it to construct their username@facebook.com email address.

This also allows your users to opt-out by not including their Facebook username, if they don't want the Facebook message notifications.

Comment: What if some user don`t have username? For details see the screenshot bellow.
[link](http://shot.qip.ru/00QTz6-42Q3rLtob/)

Comment: See below for answer. It was a bit much for a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

For users who don't have a set username through Facebook, there is no way to email them. Facebook does not allow messages to be sent via email using a user's ID - only their set username.

However, with a bit of quick research regarding these IDs, it looks like Facebook has completely discontinued this e-mail service. As multiple articles turned up, it sounds like the email-to-Facebook-message service ended in 2014, though Facebook would still forward emails to username@facebook.com to that user's set primary email address (so if someone emailed username@facebook.com, the message would appear in that user's primary email address, i.e. myFakeEmail@gmail.com). That message-forwarding service appears to have ended in ~May 2016.

If you still want to test this for yourself, you can; but even if it somehow still works, Facebook has never supported email-to-ID, so that unfortunately won't be possible.

Comment: thx for answer! Maybe there is another way for sending messages to FB??

Comment: The only way to currently send an external message to FB is (a) post to a group / page - i.e. if you share the update from your website to a FB page that your members can join, and they can opt to get notifications when you post. Or (b) using Facebook messenger SMS (currently on Android only, as far as I can tell) - http://www.pcmag.com/news/345273/send-receive-sms-texts-in-facebook-messenger-on-android - though that would require your users to opt-in to that setting, and give you their phone number, so the text would appear in FB messenger on mobile.